# Is it possible to debug a 3rd-party python file inside a Jupyter notebook cell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

`set_trace()` enables debug our own code inside a Jupyter notebook cell.

code_snippet_1

```
#import the KNeighborsClassifier class from sklearn
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace
#import metrics model to check the accuracy 
from sklearn import metrics
#Try running from k=1 through 25 and record testing accuracy
k_range = range(1,26)
scores = {}
scores_list = []
for k in k_range:
    set_trace()
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred=knn.predict(X_test)
    scores[k] = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
    scores_list.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

this is part of "KNN on Iris Datset" source code.

this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1s13Z6Isf_nHAD85t0J-mx1oTaMNAdCyr) is the whole piece which could be 100% reproducible online.

the question is

Is it possible to debug a 3rd-party python file, such as `classification.py` inside a Jupyter notebook cell?

in particular, is it possible to debug a `knn.predict()` inside a Jupyter notebook cell?

which is located in

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py
```

this piece

```
y_pred=knn.predict(["trap", X_test])

%debug
```

gets this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-054b4ff1b356> in <module>()
----> 1 y_pred=knn.predict(["trap", X_test])
      2 
      3 get_ipython().magic('debug')
```

...

## only run this single line

```
y_pred=knn.predict(["trap", X_test])
```

gets this error (the long array output has been removed)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-054b4ff1b356> in <module>()
----> 1 y_pred=knn.predict(["trap", X_test])
      2 
      3 get_ipython().magic('debug')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    519                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    520                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 521                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    522 
    523         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes
```

right after the error, I ran `%debug` in a new cell, and then I got this error

```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py(521)check_array()
    519                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    520                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 521                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    522 
    523         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes
```

and ipdb input

[image]

I entered `up` , pdb switched to `classification.py`

set breakpoint

[image]

and then `up`, switch back,

[image]

the breakpoint didn't work

here is the whole logging

```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py(521)check_array()
    519                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    520                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 521                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    522 
    523         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes

ipdb> up
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py(147)predict()
    145             Class labels for each data sample.
    146         """
--> 147         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
    148 
1   149         neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)

ipdb> b
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py:149
2   breakpoint   keep yes   at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py:150
ipdb> up
> <ipython-input-22-be2dbe619b73>(2)<module>()
      1 X = ["trap", X_test]
----> 2 y_pred=knn.predict(X)

ipdb> X = X_test
ipdb> s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De facto it is not possible to do it. But there is a trick. You can pass in a wrong argument to the `predict` function intentionally, so that it fails and you can call `%debug` in order to follow the steps line by line. See an example below.

`y_pred=knn.predict(["trap", X_test])`

This would try to execute the `predict` method and would fail because you are inputing a random list instead of an array. You can take on the execution from there calling the `%debug` magic command

Comment: I've updated the OP, get some error with the trick, may be I am using the trick the incorrect way.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain it correctly. That's the intention! You produced an error there intentionally in order to capture it with the debugger by running `%debug` manually afterwards (in another cell and through another call)

Comment: I added a new section "only run this single line", given this particular error, what should I do next? run `%debug`? then I got `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py(521)` which is not I try to debug.

Comment: Sure, you are at that line because this is where sklearn validates the input and raises the error in case it is not valid. Now you have to navigate the traceback to go to the point you want. You can use the`up`and `down` commands to go up and down in the traceback. Once you are on a higher point from what you want to debug, you can set a break point using the `break`command and run the code with the input corrected. More info about the pdb here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: I can set `break` even if it is a 3rd-party python file, such as /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py, right?

Comment: Exactly! :D There's no difference between your code and 3rd party code but the location of the file :D

Comment: If I managed to help you, please remember to vote me and select the answer as valid answer :D

Comment: Sure, You are awesome! We are very close. Please take a look at the last part, How can I run code_snippet_1 from pdb? or should I quit pdb? I did quit. and run whole piece, break point didn't work.

Comment: should I define a function before all this, and trick to launch pdb, and navigate back, and call that function from pdb?

Comment: No, you should run "code_snipped_1" and integrate the trick there. Then run it expecting a fail and run `%debug`  in another cell. Once you `quit` from the debugger  all the set break points are reset. They only hold during the session

Comment: So basically the steps are: (1) run the code to force failure, (2) navigate the traceback and set the breakpoint, (3) fix your trick inside the debugger with something like `X = X[1]` and (4) continue the execution in the debugger  to hit the breakpoint. Once you hit it, you are in the right point for debugging. Debugging that way is a bit painful but you can manage :D

Comment: I've updated just now, please take a look at the whole logging, the break point didn't work.

Comment: I'd do several things..... (1) check that X is really updated as you specified, (2) don't run a 'step', run 'continue'. Read the pdb documentation carefully.